# How to make a new matrix based on column values in an old matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am very new to Matlab and coding in general, so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I have a matrix of three columns (`data1`) where the first column refers to time (s).

I would like to make a new matrix (`bout1`) consisting of entire rows of the matrix `data1` based on the values in the first column (so, for example, in a range from 30 s to 120 s).

I know how to extract the rows based on the row number:

```
bout1 = data1(361126:391643,:)
```

but not based on the values in a specific column.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` function (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)) to find the rows you need, like this:

```
time = data1(:, 1);
i = find(30 <= time & time <= 120);
bout1 = data1(i, :);
```

Comment: Ah thanks! That makes so much sense now that I see it ... I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome!